# Custom symfony routing based on doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, routes, doctrine-orm

I need to have dynamic routes with symfony 2 where a slug parameter is added to the url and is related to a page in the database. Each page has a own slug and its content stored in the database. I read the article [Advanced Routing](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/02-Advanced-Routing) but it's for the old version of symfony. For the new version it seems that [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) does a similar job. Is this the correct way to implement a doctrine-based routing or should I write a real custom router class?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a dynamic route, please?

Comment: sure, I mean that I have the content of each page in the database with a slug column in the table that serves as "url". When I digit domain.com/test test is the slug and is dynamic

Comment: If you are talking about slugs, you should get everything you want on the Symfony2 doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Comment: Ok you need slugs, so read the documentation for version 2

Comment: so it's more appropriate for a doctrine-based routing to have a controller that does the query?

Comment: @Stefano - @ParamConverter#Doctrine Converter does the job similar to symfony 1. If you want to skip the magic - "have controller that does the query..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a ParamConverter, yes. The default [DoctrineParamConverter](https://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Request/ParamConverter/DoctrineParamConverter.php) that ships with the FrameworkExtraBundle can handle most simple cases -- that is, it knows how to look up a typehinted object by a field with the same name as the route placeholder:

```
// routing.yml
foo_route:
    pattern: /{slug}/
    defaults: { _controller: FooVendorBundle:Foo:view }

// FooVendorBundle/Controller/FooController.php
public function view(FooEntity $foo)
{
    // $foo will be an instance of FooEntity
}
```

Normally, in a controller's argument list, you'd have a `$slug` variable that would be populated from the contents of `{slug}` captured by the route. However, with the ParamConverter, it recognizes that you're requesting a `FooEntity` class, and will try to find that entity by the captured `slug` value and populate the `$foo` variable with that entity.

The default ParamConverter is, of course, limited to only being able to look up properties that actually *exist* on the entity: if FooEntity does not have a field named `slug`, the lookup will fail and an exception will be thrown. Like I said, this will handle a majority of basic use cases. If you need more in-depth conversion of request parameters, you could always write your own.

Comment: if I need to handle dynamic pages with slug but also normal pages with controllers should I use a custom router class that handles each of the page types (static and dynamic)?

Comment: I'm really starting to love symfony. +1