# Symfony2: how to set url only with the slug

Tags: symfony, routes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom symfony routing based on doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570115/custom-symfony-routing-based-on-doctrine)

I have several url in my project related to each object type. Ex.

For products:

```
/product/product-1
/product/product-2
```

But now I created a controller for general info management. Ex. terms of use, about us ..etc.

I want urls that only contains the page slug.

```
/terms-use
/about-us
```

Not:

```
/page/terms-use
/page/about-us
```

How to define this in routing.yml?

Answer (score 1):

Venu is right, [Custom symfony routing based on doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570115/custom-symfony-routing-based-on-doctrine) provides a way to do this, the only complication comes if your slug parameter is built by adding slugs of parent pages such that the grandchild page has a slug like `grandparent-slug/parent-slug/child-slug` in which case an exception would be thrown.

We used routing to match slugs like the example I gave and it required some regex in the annotations:

```
/**
 * @Route("{slug}", name="page_index", defaults={"slug" = false}, requirements={"slug" = "[0-9a-zA-Z\/\-]*"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction($slug)
{
    if ($slug !== false) {
        $page = $this->findPage($slug);
```

The above requirements annotation means that the slug can be alphanumeric with forward slashes and hyphens.  You then need to implement a method `findPage($slug)` that explodes the slug on forward slashes and finds the correct child page.

Because the route matches so many other routes, it is important to include this controller last in the routing.yml file and this action last of the public actions in the controller so that all other routes are matched first.

#### EDIT

This is the findPage method that we wrote to find a page from the above slug:

```
protected function findPage($slug_string, $first_page = false)
{
    $slug_array = explode("/", $slug_string);
    $slug = array_shift($slug_array);
    $page = $this->em->getRepository("PagesBundle:Page")->getPageBySlug($slug, $this->site_id);
    if (!$page) {
        return false;
    }
    // if only the first matched page is required return it
    if ($first_page) {
        return $page;
    }
    // Otherwise loop through the slug array and match recursive 
    //children until slug array is empty or no match found
    while (!empty($slug_array)) {
        if ($page->getChildren()) {
            $slug = array_shift($slug_array);
            foreach ($page->getChildren() as $child_page) {
                if ($child_page->getSlug() == $slug) {
                    $page = $child_page;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return $page;
}
```